# Embedding layer in Pytorch NN for GAN

Tags: python, pytorch, word-embedding, generative-adversarial-network

I created an emedding layer, using pretrained GloVe (glove.twitter.27B.25d.txt) for my generator that is part of a GAN for tweet generation. This layer has size `Embedding(5119, 25)`, where 5119 is the size of my vocab and 25 is the size of the vector with the embedded word. My input data is a torch tensor (with indexes of words corresponding to the vocab) of size [53, 20], where 53 is the lenght of a padded tweet, 20 is the batch_size. Now I'm not sure how to implement the embedding layer in my generator.

```
emb = nn.Embedding.from_pretrained(torch.FloatTensor(weights_matrix))

class Generator(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.model = nn.Sequential(
            emb,
            nn.Linear(lendata, batch_size),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(batch_size, 32),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(32, lendata),
        )
        
    def forward(self, x):
        output = self.model(x)
        print(output)
        return output

generator = Generator()

latent_space_samples = torch.zeros((lendata, batch_size)).long()

generated_samples = generator(latent_space_samples)
```

I need to put the real and generated samples together, in order to put them in the discriminator
`all_samples = torch.cat((real_samples, generated_samples))`

But the generated samples now have the following size: torch.Size([53, 20, 25]) and the real samples have the size of the input data torch.Size([53, 20]). I understand the error I get, `RuntimeError: Tensors must have same number of dimensions: got 2 and 3`
But I don't know how to get the outputs the same dimsensions

I don't understand what's happening and what I should do to properly pass it to the discriminator. Is it even right what I'm doing with the embedding? And is the code for my generator okay?